# excel.make_response_from_query_sets returning TypeError None

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, flask, typeerror

I'm attempting to have my flask project export a simple SQLite database query into an XLS excel file.  The rest of the script works quite handily and without issue, but I seem to be misunderstanding the parameters for this.

I've closely examined the flask-excel documentation and believe that my implementation should be working fine, however, execution of the code provides a TypeError.

Full disclosure, this is my second day working with Python and I am a bit beyond my capabilities it seems!

The function in question is as follows:

```
@app.route("/updatePrint", methods=['GET'])
def updatePrint():
    query_sets = session.query(Products).all()
    column_names = ['title', 'type', 'components', 'region', 'producer', 'blurb', 'desc1', 'desc2', 'pairing','pretax','posttax']
    return excel.make_response_from_query_sets(query_sets, column_names, "xls", file_name="export_data") , render_template('updatePrint.html')
```

As mentioned, the script returns the following type error

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

I am not sure why this is seemingly returning nothing (I assume that's what's happening).  I'm happy to provide further code if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: `return excel.make_response_from_query_sets(query_sets, column_names, "xls", file_name="export_data")` without `render_template('updatePrint.html')`

Comment: Hi folks, the solution to this issue was to provide ```excel.init_excel(app)``` at the beginning of this app.  Woops.

Answer (score 0):

Works by initialising it at the top:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
excel.init_excel(app)
```

Doesn't work inside a function with the error stated:

```
@app.route('/export', methods=['GET'])
def Export():
    excel.init_excel(app)
```